# Срезы тензоров по индексам. tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Допустим есть тензор v, который имеет размерность [N, 1]. Мне нужно выяснить индексы элементов, которые больше некоторого числа: tf.where(v > vpeak). На выходе получаю следующее (для N = 7):

```
[[0 0]  
[1 0]  
[2 0]  
[5 0]]
```

---

Есть тензор omega [N, N]. Мне нужно получить его срез следующим образом:
во всех строках оставить только те столбцы, которые соответствуют индексам удовлетворяющим условию v > vpeak. 
Если сделать срез того, что получилось (после применения where):

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
```

и получается проблема, что я не могу правильно их поставить в

`tf.slice(omega, [0, 0], [N, ?])`

В numpy я делал это легко, но хочу использовать именно tensorflow и не использовать циклы.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел возможное решение. Пусть у меня есть

```
index = [1, 2, 3],
```

где 1, 2, 3 - нумера столбцов.

```
tf.transpose(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tf.transpose(omega), index))
```

Возможно, что есть более изящное решение.